# DLQueryExample could not load ontology

Tags: java, ontology

DLQueryExample given worked . but when i changed the code to try for a new ontology , i could build the file without errors.i created the ontology using the ontology IRI http://www.semanticweb.org/name/ontologies/2013/8/insurance
 but when i tried to run it , the following problem occured.

--------------------Configuration: Samples - JDK version 1.7.0_40  - --------------------
Could not load ontology: Problem parsing string:ontology1
Could not parse ontology.  Either a suitable parser could not be found, or parsing failed.  See parser logs below for explanation.
The following parsers were tried:
1) RDFXMLParser
2) OWLXMLParser
3) OWLFunctionalSyntaxOWLParser
4) TurtleOntologyParser
5) OWLOBOParser
6) KRSS2OWLParser
7) ManchesterOWLSyntaxOntologyParser

### Detailed logs:

Parser: RDFXMLParser
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: string:ontology1; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 40; Element type "rdf:about" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

---

Parser: OWLXMLParser
Attribute not found: IRI (Line 3)

---

Parser: OWLFunctionalSyntaxOWLParser
Encountered "  "< "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting:
    "Ontology" ...
     (Line 0)

---

Parser: TurtleOntologyParser
uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.turtle.parser.ParseException: Encountered "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:

---

Parser: OWLOBOParser
org.coode.owlapi.obo.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 22.  Encountered: "\n" (10), after : ""

---

Parser: KRSS2OWLParser
de.uulm.ecs.ai.owlapi.krssparser.ParseException: Encountered " ">" " "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting:

---

Parser: ManchesterOWLSyntaxOntologyParser
Encountered '' at line 1 column 1.  Expected either 'Ontology:' or 'Prefix:' (Line 1)

Process completed.

how could i resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to access the ontology that you linked gave me a 404 error. If that was the case at the time you ran your experiment, that would explain the issue - the HTML returned in the 404 is not a parseable ontology, hence the failure.
The error message from the API could be clearer, though.